# Cache Entity Framework query results for next postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

I have a common scenario where i query the DB for different sets of values to fill some drop-downs in a given form.

i have a lot of the and it takes 4-5 seconds to retrieve the list of values for each drop-down.

is there any way i can cache this information on the server as this kind of information is not changing very often ..

here is part of my code asking for values...

```
AvailablePaperSizes = i_Context.PaperSizes.ToList();
AvailablePaperTypes = i_Context.PaperTypes.ToList();
AvailablePaperColors = i_Context.PaperColors.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

4-5 seconds per list? If each list can fit in a drop-down control, I would firstly try to find out why it's taking so long.

In any case, you can create a compiled query and store it in a static instance in your context class. The query will be ran the first time it's accessed (which you can put in `Application_Start` or similar) and the result set stored in memory. Every subsequent time the method is called it will be look into the memory for the result set rather than query the database.

A useful helper method is the following:

```
public partial class AppContext: ObjectContext
{
    private static readonly Func<AppContext, IEnumerable<PaperSizes>> pSizes = CompiledQuery.Compile(
        (AppContext context) => context.PaperSizes.ToList()
        );

    public IEnumerable<PaperSizes> GetAllPaperSizes() 
    {
        return pSizes.Invoke(this).ToList();
    }
 }
```

You can use it as follows to fill in your drop-down list:

```
AvailablePaperSizes = i_Context.GetAllPaperSizes();
```

Ditto for all other collections.